# Have a optional second parameter in Typescript type

Tags: typescript, types

I have these two, very similar types:

```
import { VariantProps } from "@stitches/core";

export type VariantOption<
  Component extends { [key: symbol | string]: any },
  VariantName extends keyof VariantProps<Component>
> = Extract<VariantProps<Component>[VariantName], string>;

export type Variants<
  Component extends { [key: symbol | string]: any }
> = Extract<VariantProps<Component>, string>;
```

As can be seen here they are both very similar, the only difference being that the second type doesn't take a second generic parameter, so it doesn't take that index from the `VariantProps<Component>` type.

Is it possible to merge them both, having the second parameter be optional and change the result based on it being not set?

It would be something like this (not valid syntax):

```
import { VariantProps } from "@stitches/core";

export type VariantOption<
  Component extends { [key: symbol | string]: any },
  VariantName? extends keyof VariantProps<Component>
> = VariantName ?
        Extract<VariantProps<Component>[VariantName], string> :
        Extract<VariantProps<Component>, string>;
```

Comment: The `typescript-typings` tag is specifically for type packages and not for general questions regarding types in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a "default" value for a generic like so:

```js
type Foo<X extends string, Y extends object = {baz: string}> = {
    xParam: X;
    yParam: Y;
}
```

In your case it would be something like `VariantName extends keyof VariantProps<Component> = ???` where ??? is the default type you would want.

Depending on your desired use case, you could get a bit more fancy with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to "change the result based on it being not set" as you say:

```js
// yParam is "null" if second generic type is not specificed
type Foo<X extends string, Y extends object | unknown = unknown> = {
    xParam: X;
    yParam: Y extends object ? Y : null;
}

type Bar = Foo<'hello', {}>;
/*
type Bar = {
    xParam: "hello";
    yParam: {};
}
*/

type Baz = Foo<'world'>;
/*
type Baz = {
    xParam: "world";
    yParam: null;
}
*/
```

Edit: if I understand your desired behavior based on your question, this might work:

```js
export type VariantOption<
  Component extends { [key: symbol | string]: any },
  VariantName extends keyof VariantProps<Component> | unknown = unknown
> = VariantName extends keyof VariantProps<Component>
  ? Extract<VariantProps<Component>[VariantName], string>
  : Extract<VariantProps<Component>, string>;
```

Comment: I found the documentation for conditional types and I just tried exactly what you mentioned in your edit, that would be my desired behavior. But then I got two "issues", only one of them is a main issue actually. I put screenshots with descriptions on imgur: https://imgur.com/a/RDN78na

Comment: @Phiter that seems like a different issue than the one you described since it happens even when using your `Variants` generic directly. In other words, if you are having trouble using the `VariantProps` utility type from `@stiches/core`, you should post a separate question about it.

Comment: It seems like you have an issue with `Extract<>`, perhaps you are misusing it? What is your desired outcome exactly?

Comment: I think the autocomplete issue is related to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729).